# Opening command prompt as an administrator

Tags: windows, windows-vista, administrator

There's a hidden folder in windows vista, but no available when I show hidden files: I need to open `cmd` as administrator.

The folder is named `c:\folder.000` and there are `c:\folder.000\dir0000.chk` folders on it. Why cant I see it on Windows Explorer, but can see it when using cmd as administrator? How can I search if there are similar folders like this on `c:`?

**EDIT**: The folder has two attribues, `SH` (System and Hidden).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might be a `system` file folder. Uncheck the checkbox says `hide system files...` (or something like this) in folder options.

you can change the attributes of the file using `attrib` command:

```
attrib -s c:\folder.000 /s /d
```

removes `system` attribute.

to list all files with special attribute you can use this:

```
dir c: /S /A:S
```

lists all system files.

Comment: The folder had two attributes: H and S. When you need to remove two attrib, you need to remove them **at the same time**. So I needed to run your command doing `attrib -S -H c:\folder.000 /S /D`. I dont know if calling the parameters as lowercase would work, because other tutorials about this command in Vista were using uppercase. But thanks for the `attrib` hint, without it I couldn't solve my problem! :) (You can edit your answer to have the removal of both attributes).

Comment: +1 for your answer, but please don't just change attributes willy-nilly!  They're there for a reason.

Comment: @89874yh I agree with Hand-E-Food, instead of changing the attributes, configure `Explorer` to show hidden and system files, attribute changing in my answer is kinda a FYI thing.